# Split a string, sort it, then concatenate the resulting splits in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I am trying to split a string based on a specific character, and then order the resulting strings depending on some specific order and then concatenate them into a new string.

**Example:** consider numeric order and `-` as a separator
`1-5-2-3` should become `1-2-3-5`.

Is there any way to achieve that?

My first try is splitting using regular expressions and then compare the results each resulting split with its next, however, this does not work as there is no way to store the intermediate resulting string.

```
SELECT ?url ?url1

WHERE {

  BIND ("1-2-3" as ?urls)
  VALUES ?n {0 1 2  } # Split at most 10 URLs mangled together
  VALUES ?m {0 1 2  }

  BIND (concat("^((.+?-)?){", str(?n) ,"} *") AS ?newvar)
  BIND (replace(?urls, ?newvar, "") AS ?remaining)
  BIND (replace(?remaining, "-.+", "") AS ?url)

  BIND (concat("^((.+?-)?){", str(?n + 1) ,"} *") AS ?newvar1)
  BIND (replace(?urls, ?newvar1, "") AS ?remaining1)
  BIND (replace(?remaining1, "-.+", "") AS ?url1)

}
```

Comment: SPARQL is not meant to be the only tool in your kit. Is there a reason you are not using another programming/scripting language for this task?

Comment: @TallTed Yes, there is a reason that I would like to get it solved in SPARQL...

Comment: The thing is, SPARQL isn't a procedural language. Execution of your sample query doesn't proceed from top to bottom. You *might* be able to build a stack of subqueries, remembering that SPARQL executes subqueries from "inside-out" (often referred to as "bottom-up", but this can be misunderstood) — so the innermost subquery is executed first, followed by the second-innermost, and the third-innermost, etc., until the outermost.

Comment: You might be better served by a multi-model, multi-language query processor, something like [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) (from my employer) that provides both SPARQL and SQL, and lets you combine the two -- with inline SPARQL-within-SQL, a/k/a SPASQL; and with SQL Stored Procedures within SPARQL.